# ISNULL function within select command of formview

Tags: sql-server-2008, formview, isnull

This is part of my select statement within an formview which works fine till it hits a null value during the update process.

```
 (SELECT TOP 1 F.tel_id FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id = @id
 ORDER BY sort_no ) AS faxid
```

so i tried using the ISNULL function in the following way but it throws error. how can it be done?

```
ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 F.tel_id FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id= @id ORDER BY sort_no ) AS faxid ,0) AS faxid
```

Comment: I "like it" when people say "it throws error". Please tell us what error was thrown.

Comment: Can you show the Update query?

Comment: What type is `F.tel_id`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've found the cause of the problem. And if that is really the one then I'm almost certain that someone else would have spotted it sooner than I did if you had formatted your second code snippet more nicely.

So, here goes your code snippet, slightly reformatted:

```
ISNULL(
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 F.tel_id
    FROM TELEPHONE as F
    where F.tel_type_id = 3
      AND F.client_id= @id
    ORDER BY sort_no
  ) AS faxid,
  0
) AS faxid
```

The highlighted part, the `AS fixed` bit immediately after the subquery, is erroneous, it just shouldn't be there. Probably you just overlooked it.

Comment: exactly, as i said to the other comment i made two alias :) thanx for rectifying!!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't read the comments carefully. You never said explicitly about the two aliases but your corrected code in one of the comments shows that you had already found the problem by the time I posted my answer. You should have posted that either as an answer or at least as an update to your question so it would be more obvious for others to see that the problem was solved. In any event, congratulations on figuring that out! :)

Comment: hi andriy...i tried to post it as an answer but the site didn't allow me to post as "answer" to my own question within like 8 hrs. anyway thx for sticking with me !!

Answer (score 2):

Your ISNULL needs to be around F.tel_id

Try

```
SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(F.tel_id, 0) FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id = @id ORDER BY sort_no
```

Comment: this doesnt change the null value to zero when i executed in the sql query. but i tried this and it works fine!!                ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1  F.tel_id FROM TELEPHONE as F where F.tel_type_id = 3 AND F.client_id = 1 ORDER BY sort_no ),0)AS faxid                        thanx for the response!

Comment: @debutante, you need to give us some more information then. What is your error, and what is your update command?

Comment: My error was when the selected value returned NULL i couldn't convert it to int in the code behind file. so i need to replace the null value by zero. and as i said the above code works fine! thanx again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to return something other than null. So when your query executes and has a value it is returned else the value you specify is returned.